# Azure DevOps - Rules, make required attachments on state change

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I'm new to Azure Dev Ops and I'm trying to make a field required when State changes. For example, when the State Changes to Approver, the Reviewer Sign Off should be required. When I wrote the attached rule, it is not working. [Rule Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKKZf.png)

The fields are On/Off [fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsCej.png). Can you please advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the azure devops work item if we use the Boolean type of the fields. Then this field will be set to Require as default and we cannot change it.
And according to our call, I update my answer and help you create a demo.

**Update**

This is used to change state to Reviewer. And here are the steps:

1. Since we cannot use the Boolean type of the fields to help us set the required. So, we need to use another field to help us to do it. Here I use the Date/Time type. [image]
2. We need to associate the field Review Sign Off and Review Sign Off Time. So we need to create other five rules (Two of them are used to prevent disoperation).

Here are the details:

**Note**: My test state is New -> fa -> Rev -> Close; this demo is used to set the rule from fa->Rev

1. Create the ChangeState rule:[image]
2. Create the SetTime rule: [image]
3. Create the ReadOnly rule: When the state was not the state before the Rev, make the sign off read-only [image]
4. Create two other rule to prevent disoperation: [image] [image]

Comment: thank you for answering Yujun. My bad, I just noticed my screenshot and it says Read Only for Reviewer Sign Off. However, what I meant was Make Required for Reviewer Sign Off and not Read Only. [New Rule] (https://imgur.com/a/8n9BtQd)

Comment: Hi@droidmaterial, if we use the Boolean type of the fields, we do not need to set the  Reviewer Sign Off Required, because the Boolean type is set to Required be default. It means if we create the WorkItem, then the field 'Reviewer Sign Off' has been set.